# How to create a developer account for Google Apps for Work

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I am developing an app that uses Directory API to create user accounts within Google Apps for Work. I have been testing this on a Free (legacy) account but now I need to test adding and removing domains, which Free account doesn't support. I don't want to get a paid account just yet and rack up a huge bill by adding and removing accounts in testing. I also don't see a way to get a sandbox/developer account to test this out. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: with 2 test users, $10 isnt a huge bill if you only pay it for one month.

Comment: The test care requires multiple domains with multiple users per domain, this will be significantly more than 2 users.